# How to calculate Frequency of Directly Follow activity from record data using SQL Query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

Currently, I am doing an ETL task from record data for process mining task. The goal is to make a "Directly Follow (DF)" Matrix based on the record data. This is the flow:

I have a **record (event) data**, for example:

```
ID  ev_ID   Act      Complete
1    1       A       2020-01-13 11:46
2    1       B       2020-01-13 11:50
3    1       C       2020-01-13 11:55
4    1       D       2020-01-13 12:50
5    1       E       2020-01-13 12:52
6    2       A       2020-01-06 09:13
7    2       B       2020-01-06 09:15
8    2       C       2020-01-06 11:46
9    2       D       2020-01-06 11:46
10   3       A       2020-01-06 08:11
11   3       C       2020-01-06 08:10
12   3       B       2020-01-06 09:46
13   3       D       2020-01-06 11:23
14   3       E       2020-01-06 16:05
```

As I mentioned above, I want to create a DF matrix that shows the "direct follow relation" [see here](https://process-mining.tistory.com/23). However, I want to change the output with a **table representation** (not a matrix).

**The (desired) output:**

```
From    To    Frequency
A       A     0
A       B     3
A       C     1
…       …     … 
D       E     2
…       …     … 
E       E     0
```

The idea is to calculate the frequency of "direct follow relation" *for each activity per ev_id*. For example:

- We have ev_1 = [ABCD]
- The ev_1 has direct follow relation: AB, BC, and CD.
- So, we can calculate the direct follow frequency for each activity.

**My question:**
Is there anyone who can suggest how to make the output using a SQL query?
I am doing the task with *PostgreSQL* now.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

I tried by myself, but the result seems not correctly 100%.
This is my code:

```
with ev_data as (
select 
    ID as eid,
    ev_ID as ci, 
    Act as ea, 
    Complete as ec
from 
    table_name
),
A0 as (
select 
    eid,
    ci::int,
    row_number() over (partition by ci order by ci, ec) as idx,
    ea as act1,
    ea as act2
from
    ev_data
),
A1 as (
select 
    L1.ci as ci1,
    L1.idx as idx1,
    L1.act1 as afrom,
    L2.ci as ci2,
    L2.idx as idx2,
    L2.act2 as ato
from A0 as L1
join  A0 as L2
on L1.ci = L2.ci
and L2.idx = L1.idx + 1
) 
select 
    afrom,
    ato,
    count(*) as count
from A1 
group by afrom, ato
order by afrom
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  You show a matrix with from/to that has two `act`s.  Then you seem to have more.  What are you really trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your comment. I am sorry if my question is not clear. To clarify, I edited the question above. Actually, I'd like to calculate the directly follow frequency for each activity per ev_id. Instead of using matrix representation for the output, I changed the output with the table representation that I mentioned. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that your goal is the first matrix.  You have two issues:

- Getting the adjacent counts.
- Generating the rows with `0` values.

Neither is really difficult.  The first uses `lead()` and aggregation.  The second uses `cross join`:

```
select a_f.act_from, a_t.act_to,
       count(t.id)
from (select distinct act as act_from from table_name
     ) a_f cross join
     (select distinct act as act_to from table_name
     ) a_t left join
     (select t.*,
             lead(act) over (partition by ev_id order by complete) as next_act
      from table_name t
     ) t
     on t.act = a_f.act_from and
        t.next_act = a_t.act_to
group by a_f.act_from, a_t.act_to;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution, and I got the result. I learn something from you. Thank you very much ~